# How to use/install rtree in sqlite3 module in python 2.7 on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, sqlite, spatialite

I'm trying to use spatialite database with my django project that is using contrib.gis application (GeoDjango). When syncing database django gives an error "no such module: rtree". Apparently the sqlite3 module that ships with python 2.7.3 doesn't support rtree in sqlite database.

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

You need to build sqlite with the

```
SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE
```

flag set. How you do that depends on your environment, but typically adding something like:

-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1

to your compiler flags will usually be enough.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to install a [spatial backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/) such as spatiallite see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspatialite