# rtree error in Python 2.7 (Win10)

Tags: python-2.7

I am running Python 2.7 on Win10. I am getting this error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such module: rtree. And I have rtree installed!
Is this an OS issues or Python version? Works fine on Mac OSX.

```
File "frequent.py", line 183, in <module>
getTablesNColumns()
File "frequent.py", line 21, in getTablesNColumns
cur.exeNFO({})'.format(table[0]))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such module: rtree
```

Comment: I can attach the script if needed

Comment: this answer may be helpfiul [How to use/install rtree in sqlite3 module in python 2.7 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20941500/1248974), I know you said you have `rtree` installed, but did you "set the necessary flags" when you installed `rtree`?